Prove $\forall x\forall y \neg R(x,y) \wedge \neg \exists x\forall y\neg R(F(x),y)$ is a contradiction by natural deduction
Problem: Prove by natural deduction that the formula $$\forall x\forall y \neg R(x,y) \wedge \neg \exists x\forall y\neg R(F(x),y)$$ is a contradiction.
So far: Here $R$ is a relation and $F$ a unary function symbol in our vocabulary. By eliminating the $\wedge$ and $\forall$, we get $\neg R(x,y)$. I know I want to do the same to the second disjunct, eliminate the $\wedge$, and then deduce $R(x,y)$. This ''sub''-deduction is the one I'm stuck on. I'm most comfortable with tree style proofs.

Depending on your rules/definitions, you will want to show that $∃x∀y¬R(F(x),y)$ follows from $\forall x \forall y \neg R(x,y)$, which implies a contradiction given the assumption.

A formula is a contradiction if and only if its truth value is always false, and a formula such as $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is always false whenever at least one conjunct is false. Without loss of generality, let us consider the left conjunct $\alpha$. If it is false, then the entire formula $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is immediately false and the truth value of the right conjunct $\beta$ is irrelevant. However, if $\alpha$ is true, then the entire formula $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is false if and only if the right conjunct $\beta$ is false. Equivalently, if $\alpha$ is true, then the entire formula $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is false if and only if the negation of the right conjunct, that is, $\neg \beta$, is true. Hence, we can show $\alpha \wedge \beta$ is a contradiction by deriving the negation of the right conjunct, that is, $\neg \beta$, under the assumption the left conjunct $\alpha$ is true.
Now, let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the formulas $\forall x \forall y \neg R(x,y)$ and $\neg \exists x \forall y \neg R(F(x),y)$, respectively. Then, we can show $\forall x \forall y \neg R(x,y) \wedge \neg \exists x \forall y \neg R(F(x),y)$ is a contradiction by deriving the negation of the right conjunct, that is, $\neg \neg \exists x \forall y \neg R(F(x),y) \equiv \exists x \forall y \neg R(F(x),y)$, under the assumption the left conjunct $\forall x \forall y \neg R(x,y)$ is true. In other words, we must prove
$$ \forall x \forall y \neg R(x,y) \vdash \exists x \forall y \neg R(F(x),y) $$
Note the right conjunct implies there exists a function $F: D \to D$ where $D$ is the domain of discourse. So, we may utilize an additional premise, that is, $\forall x \exists y [F(x)=y]$, which we obtain by the definition of function, and the argument we must prove is now
$$ \forall x \forall y \neg R(x,y), \forall x \exists y [F(x)=y] \vdash \exists x \forall y \neg R(F(x),y) $$
Proof:
$
\begin{array}{llll}
\{1\} & 1. & \forall x \forall y \neg R(x,y) & \text{Premise} \\
\{2\} & 2. & \forall x \exists y [F(x)=y] & \text{Premise} \\
\{2\} & 3. & \exists y [F(a)=y] & \text{2 Universal Elimination} \\
\{4\} & 4. & F(a)=b & \text{Assumption of Typical Disjunct} \\
\{1\} & 5. & \forall y \neg R(b,y) & \text{1 Universal Elimination} \\
\{1,4\} & 6. & \forall y \neg R(F(a),y) & \text{4,5 Identity Elimination} \\
\{1,4\} & 7. & \exists x \forall y \neg R(F(x),y) & \text{6 Existential Introduction} \\
\{1,2\} & 8. & \exists x \forall y \neg R(F(x),y) & \text{3,4,7 Existential Elimination} & \square \\
\end{array}
$

I've copied the problem exactly as it was given to us. Our definition of $F$ in general is a map from the domain of a structure to itself.
